# Android HTML Jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

Im trying to get the absolute URLs for images from my collages news website but have so far been unsuccessful. I am working from this site http://www.dcu.ie/news/index.shtml. As you can see from the source the first image has the absolute URL but the remainder only have the relative URLs. I have tried examples from Jsoups documentation but cant get it to work. This displays the first image and then empty boxes for the rest. I'd appreciate any help possible.Thanks

```
public class NewsActivity extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    String test2 = "<html><body>";
    Document docs;
    public void main(String... args) 
        {
        try 
        {
        docs = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dcu.ie/news/index.shtml").get();
    } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        Elements imgs = docs.select("img[src$=.jpg]");
        for (Element img : imgs) 
        {
            String url = img.toString();
            test2 = test2 + " " + url + " ";
        }
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        main();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new NewsClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadData(test2, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`Element#absUrl()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#absUrl%28java.lang.String%29) to extract the absolute URL instead of `Element#toString()` to get the text representation of the whole HTML element.

```
Elements imgs = docs.select("img[src$=.jpg]");
for (Element img : imgs) {
    String url = img.absUrl("src");
    String newImg = "<img src=\"" + url + "\"/>";
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Should there be something different in the absUrl("href") part or should it be left as href? This didnt work for me....

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I had `<a>` in mind, it should be `src`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much you're a lifesaver! My code had become green with comments of all the ways I'd tried and its so easy in the end! So now I've organised the images with their tags in a table format and I want them to be able to continue to the full article when clicked...any advice there? Webview doesn't do anything when they are clicked even though they are links...and can I parse the resulting page? Thanks again