# Parsing several HTML from a String list

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

Currently I am trying to parse several URLs given a string of them, I am using the following code:

```
for(String urlSpec : SpecificUrl) {

        try {
            result = Jsoup.connect(urlSpec).get();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Malformed URL");
        }

        urlDocument.add(result);

}
```

urlDocument is an array of Documents that I pass to another method, which then gets me the info I want. The app works fine, however, it takes very long for the Jsoup to get the documents for each url, right now I am testing with just 10 and it takes about 30 secs to a min, for the final app I am expecting to have at least 200 URLs. I have tried several methods but cant come up with a good solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274475/android-html-jsoup?rq=1 Look into this. This shall give you some idea.

Comment: write 2 threads with of of SpecificUrl half and half data

Comment: Why do not you use AsyncTask? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html